# где посмотреть все доступные ЗАШИТЫЕ пространства имён которые можно использовать в XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

начинаю изучать WPF,
возникли вопросы:

- где посмотреть все доступные ЗАШИТЫЕ пространства имён которые можно использовать в XAML?
- где посмотреть конкретно какие пространства имён .Net отображаются на каждом зашитом пространстве имён XAML?

Спасибо!

Comment: Как вы понимаете `ЗАШИТЫЕ пространства имён которые можно использовать в XAML`?

Comment: "Зашитые пр.им." - это термин из книжки Натана Адама WPF4 Подробное руководство

xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

Comment: В следующий раз поясняйте ваши терминологии сразу, так и нам легче и вы, получите ответ быстрее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос не совсем корректен, но я попытаюсь ответить.
Итак, *никакие пространства имен в XAML не "зашиты", можно объявлять и использовать любые пространства имен*, например:

```
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
```

НО, для удобства, можно назначить один алиас для группы пространств имен и, после объявления этого алиаса в XAML, использовать всё что в нем лежит, так сделано со штатными пространствами имен из BCL, например:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
```

Делается это с помощью атрибута [`XmlnsDefinition`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute), который используется на уровне сборки (например, в Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs)

Если вы хотите узнать, что скрывается под штатными алиасами (под тем же `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation`) или под алиасами, которые добавляет какая-нибудь библиотека, необходимо смотреть исходники.

Пример в PresentationFramework: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/OtherAssemblyAttrs.cs

```
// Namespace information for Xaml
[assembly:System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Controls")]
[assembly:System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Documents")]
[assembly:System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Shapes")]
[assembly:System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Shell")]
[assembly:System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Navigation")]
[assembly:System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Data")]
[assembly:System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows")]
[assembly:System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Controls.Primitives")]
[assembly:System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Media.Animation")]
[assembly:System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Input")]
[assembly: System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Media")]
```

Т.е. под `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation` скрываются пространства имен:

```
System.Windows.Controls
System.Windows.Documents
System.Windows.Shapes
System.Windows.Shell
System.Windows.Navigation
System.Windows.Data
System.Windows
System.Windows.Controls.Primitives
System.Windows.Media.Animation
System.Windows.Input
System.Windows.Media
```