# Как использовать один xmlns для нескольких clr-namespace в XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Известно, что можно прописать в XAML `clr-namespace` в формате.

```xml
<Window xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">
```

Более того, студия сама это всё прописывает. Но становится весьма неудобно, когда этих нэймспэйсов становится всё больше и больше в проекте, например.

```
WpfApp1
WpfApp1.Views
WpfApp1.ViewModels
WpfApp1.Controls
```

И по тем или иным причинам одним `xmlns:local` не обойтись, при этом прописывать эту кучу в почти каждый `ResourceDictionary` или `UserControl` не удобно. Да и принцип DRY как бы намекает, что должно быть решение.

Но как работает вот это?

```xml
<Window xmlns:local="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
```

Ведь если подключить этот нэймспейс, то в XAML будет доступна куча контролов из разных нэйспейсов .NET. Очевидно, что эти XSD схемы не приезжают из сети, а где-то хранятся или как-то генерируются.

Как сделать такое для своего собственного приложения или библиотеки, своих собственных нэймспейсов?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1149381/218063

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разбирая данный вопрос, я после весьма длительных поисков по англоязычному интернету наткнулся на вот [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34635758/12888024). При этом родная документация от Microsoft ничего вменяемого по этому поводу мне не сказала. Возможно документация и есть, но я даже теперь, зная что искать, не нашел документа, нашел только [это](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111911/A-Guide-to-Cleaner-XAML-with-Custom-Namespaces-and).

***Важно:** xmlns идентифицируется по URL, но это совсем не означает, что этот XSD файл с этого урла можно скачать, его там может и не быть. Дело в том, что по стандартам W3C имя XML нэймспейса - это URL. То есть это не его адрес, а его имя. Поэтому не стоит думать, что для задания своего неймспейса нужно иметь свой HTTP сервер и хранить там XSD файлы.*

Собственно вопрос решается, как оказалось, весьма просто.

Открыть файл **AssemblyInfo.cs** и написать там что-то типа этого

```cs
using System.Windows.Markup;

[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://localns/local", "local")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://localns/local", "WpfApp1")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://localns/local", "WpfApp1.Views")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://localns/local", "WpfApp1.ViewModels")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://localns/local", "WpfApp1.Controls")]
```

Пересобрать проект, и теперь можно в xaml файлах писать вот такое.

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:local="http://localns/local">
```

Одна строчка подключает всё что нужно. Кстати, в xaml файлах имя неймспейсу можно давать не обязательно `xmlns:local`, то есть оно не обязательно должно совпадать с тем, что указано в **AssemblyInfo.cs**.

Comment: Кстати, а вот префикс это интересно... Я и не знал что такой атрибут существует ;)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1149578/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP о, спасибо. Почему то ваш ответ никак не нагуглился.