# Как можно избавится от повторяющих ссылок в проекте WPF?

Tags: wpf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Типа в каждом окне или страницы, есть повторяющие ссылки, можно их как то вынести в один файл, и пускай оттуда берутся.

Пробовал в App.xaml, но нечего не получилось.

Вот к примеру додумались разработчики using сделать глобальными, и можно запихать в один файл и не дублировать их.

А ссылками как то можно также сделать ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 

Вот эти строчки кода поместить в один файл, и что бы они негде больше не дублировались

Comment: Совсем избавиться нельзя, это стандартный синтаксис xml и он не умеет делать что вы хотите. Но теоретически можно все необходимое перенести под одно определение и тогда в каждом файле можно будет писать только один атрибут вместо нескольких. Делается это с помощью атрибута XmlnsDefinition. Вот здесь есть ответ по теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1149578/218063 т.е. вы можете попробовать под свой кастомный дефинишн затащить все пространства имён из этих четырех

Comment: Я такого никогда не делал и на первый взгляд не понятно какие могут быть проблемы. Например, конфликты между названиями классов и т.п.

Comment: Проблемы не какой нет, просто от дублирование кода хочу избавится.

Comment: Я вам говорю не про то что у вас сейчас проблемы, а про то, что не знаю какие будут проблемы при описанном подходе. Пишите в комментариях обращение через @, иначе я не получаю уведомлений